# The use of 'trotz allem'?

Tags: word-usage, english-to-german, word-order, conjunction, particle

I'm new to German and am now studying subordinating and coordinating conjunctions. Die Wortstellung is giving a bit of trouble though. I recently learnt about 'trotz allem', but I'm not sure whether it's a subordinating conjunction just like 'trotzdem'?

Also, I came across an example of usage of 'trotz allem':

> Er bleibt trotz allem mein bester Freund.

What happens if you place 'trotz allem' at the start of a sentence? For example, if you want to translate

> Despite everything, I still feel happy for you.

to German, would it be

> Trotz allem, freue ich mich noch für dich.

Are the positions of the words correct, especially that of 'noch'?

Comment: The *noch* from the last sentence is most likely present to excuse a delay, the speaker assumes for his congratulation; alternatively the fact, that 10 persons already congratulated before. In other cases it would likely be omitted.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you got the word order right. Since “trotz allem” occupies the first position, the finite verb follows it in second position. However, in German the “trotz allem” is not separated by a comma.

Answer (score 4):

'Trotz allem' means in spite of **everything.** In this regard, it is similar, or at least "parallel," to 'trotzdem,' which means in spite of **that**.

Even though 'trotz allem' is technically two words, it is one "unit" for the purpose of occupying the first spot at the beginning of the sentence. Thus, the verb remains the second "unit," even though it is technically the third word in
'Trotz allem freue mich...' (You do not use a comma between allem and freue.)

"Trotzdem' is easier to understand because it is one unit and one word, and the verb as the second unit is also the second word. 'Trotzdem freue mich...'